# swift base64EncodedStringWithOptions us-ascii

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, base64

I'm trying to base64 encode but in us-ascii.
The problem is that bs data method
Using UTF8
Quote from the docs:

"Create a Base-64, UTF-8 encoded NSData from the receiver's contents using the given options."

Is it possible to create a base-64 us-ascii encoded?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UTF-8 and ASCII are the same for code points up to 127.  For this application the character sets are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Base 64 for is for transferring MIME types (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and all characters in Base 64 encoded string falls under ASCII.